# How to access a API returned object in Python to grab its data

Tags: python

I'm struggling with kind of a trivial issue. I call an API endpoint and receive the following `response` as an **object**:

```
{
    'data': [{
                'id': 18136910,
                'league_id': 501,
                'season_id': 18369,
                'stage_id': 77453684,
                'round_id': 247435,
                'group_id': None,
                'aggregate_id': None,
                'venue_id': 219,
             }  
             { ....
```

1. Approach: Turn object into dict and grab data

```
print(response.json().data)

# Prints AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'data'
```

2. Approach to enter the object

```
print(response.data) or print(response.data[0])

# Prints AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'
```

So how to assign e.g. 'id' to a variable `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the dict incorrectly. To get the id try:

```
print(response.json()['data'][0]['id'])
```

To access the value with key `"x"` of a dict `d` you should use `d["x"]` or `d.get("x")`.

Comment: how would I iterate over data? for item in data: ?

Comment: Yes, `for item in response.json()['data']: print(item['id'])`

Answer (score 1):

#### Try like this:

##### You need to access dict object with key.

```py
res = response.json()
print(res['data'])
```